# Syncing Thunderbird between two different (Arch) Linux Machines

Tags: thunderbird

I need to sync Thunderbird between two machines, everything, so emails, rules, add-ons, everything.

I've read that you can copy /home//.thunderbird/x7x7h7.default to the other machine, add a new profile in profiles.ini and just start it up. But when I do, Thunderbird is like it's never been used, prompting to add email account and having no content whatsoever.

Any idea where I'm going wrong? Is there other content to sync maybe?

Comment: The `~/.thunderbird/profiles.ini` file is probably wrong for the existing directory structure.  On machine B remove the `~/.thunderbird` directory or rename it to `~/.thunderbird.old` or something.  Copy over the entire `~/.thunderbird` directory from machine A.  Rules, filters, etc shouldn't change much and you should probably use imap for mail storage so that the messages always stay on the server.

Comment: Well that's odd, it's worked.  profiles.ini was correct as it was a relative path and all files were copied (profile dir and profiles.ini), no hidden files/dirs.  But copying the .thunderbird folder worked.  Feel free to post it as a solution and I'll accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ~/.thunderbird/profiles.ini file is probably wrong for the existing directory structure. On machine B remove the ~/.thunderbird directory or rename it to ~/.thunderbird.old or something. Copy over the entire ~/.thunderbird directory from machine A.

Rules, filters, etc shouldn't change much and you should probably use imap for mail storage so that the messages always stay on the server.